# Packet data using the checksum?

Tags: c#, checksum, packet

I have packet data, which I am storing as a `public static List<byte> packet = new List<byte>();`

The last byte of this is a checksum, and I am trying to figure out how to use this to check the packet data.

When I have a full packet, I run:

```
//get checksum                                    
byte chcksm = packet[packet.Count - 1];
int sum = chcksm;
```

to get the value of the checksum byte.

Then I run:

```
//checksum calculation
public static byte ComputeAdditionChecksum(List<byte> data)
{
    byte sum = 0;
    unchecked // Let overflow occur without exceptions
    {
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            sum += b;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

on `packet` to get the value of the whole packet, and save it in an int called `packetSum`.

Comparing these two vales, on a test packet,`packetSum`, the value of the whole packet, returns `76`. And the value of the checksum byte returns 103.

Am I doing this wrong?

//edit, in thedocs, it says this about the checksum..

1 Byte checksum expressed as:

```
unsigned char CalcChkSum(unsigned char *MsgBlock,
int Length)
{
    unsigned char Total = 0x40;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < Length-1; i++)
    {
        Total -= MsgBlock[i];
    }
    return Total;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're including the checksum in your calculation. Without seeing the underlying data with expected and actual results I'd say changing the loop as follows should fix the issue:

```
public static byte ComputeAdditionChecksum(List<byte> data)
{
    byte sum = 0x40;
    unchecked // Let overflow occur without exceptions
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Count - 1;  i++)
        {
            sum -= data[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense. I had to change `data.Length` to `data.Count`, as it is a list. I am still seeing odd results though, where the checksum is higher than the packet total, even though the data looks correct. I am not sure how to post byte data here is a way that will be helpful!

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies, had in my head you were using an array rather than a list. Are you sure you're calculating your checksum in the same way as the source of the data?

Comment: I am not sure of that! (am pretty new to this packet-data-stuff) What other way could i try? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read the docs for the source of the data. A checksum could be created in any arbitrary way.

Comment: Ah, got it. Just needed to convert to c#. Should have read the docs more thoroughly! Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Only difference I can see is that they subtract rather than add the value of each byte in the packet. Updated my answer...